# Why am I not seeing speed up via multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize an embarrassingly parallel for loop ([previously asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391191/embarrassingly-parallel-for-loop-with-complex-outputs-in-each-iteration)) and settled on [this implementation](https://github.com/raamana/neuropredict/blob/master/neuropredict/rhst.py#L764) that fit my parameters:

```py
    with Manager() as proxy_manager:
        shared_inputs = proxy_manager.list([datasets, train_size_common, feat_sel_size, train_perc,
                                            total_test_samples, num_classes, num_features, label_set,
                                            method_names, pos_class_index, out_results_dir, exhaustive_search])
        partial_func_holdout = partial(holdout_trial_compare_datasets, *shared_inputs)

        with Pool(processes=num_procs) as pool:
            cv_results = pool.map(partial_func_holdout, range(num_repetitions))
```

The reason I need to use a [proxy object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) (shared between processes) is the first element in the shared proxy list `datasets` that is a list of large objects (each about 200-300MB). This `datasets` list usually has 5-25 elements. I typically need to run this program on a HPC cluster.

Here is the question, when I run this program with 32 processes and 50GB of memory (num_repetitions=200, with datasets being a list of 10 objects, each 250MB), I do not see a speedup even by factor of 16 (with 32 parallel processes). I do not understand why - any clues? Any obvious mistakes, or bad choices? Where can I improve this implementation? Any alternatives?

I am sure this has been discussed before, and the reasons can be varied and very specific to implementation - hence I request you to provide me your 2 cents. Thanks.

**Update**: I did some profiling with cProfile to get a better idea - here is some info, sorted by cumulative time.

```
In [19]: p.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats(50)
Mon Oct 16 16:43:59 2017    profiling_log.txt

         555404 function calls (543552 primitive calls) in 662.201 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 4510 to 50 due to restriction <50>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    897/1    0.044    0.000  662.202  662.202 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000  662.202  662.202 test_rhst.py:2(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001  661.341  661.341 test_rhst.py:70(test_chance_classifier_binary)
        1    0.000    0.000  661.336  661.336 /Users/Reddy/dev/neuropredict/neuropredict/rhst.py:677(run)
        4    0.000    0.000  661.233  165.308 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py:533(wait)
        4    0.000    0.000  661.233  165.308 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py:263(wait)
       23  661.233   28.749  661.233   28.749 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000  661.233  661.233 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py:261(map)
        1    0.000    0.000  661.233  661.233 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py:637(get)
        1    0.000    0.000  661.233  661.233 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py:634(wait)
    866/8    0.004    0.000    0.868    0.108 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:958(_find_and_load)
    866/8    0.003    0.000    0.867    0.108 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:931(_find_and_load_unlocked)
    720/8    0.003    0.000    0.865    0.108 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:641(_load_unlocked)
    596/8    0.002    0.000    0.865    0.108 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:672(exec_module)
   1017/8    0.001    0.000    0.863    0.108 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:197(_call_with_frames_removed)
   522/51    0.001    0.000    0.765    0.015 {built-in method builtins.__import__}
```

The profiling info now sorted by `time`

```
In [20]: p.sort_stats('time').print_stats(20)
Mon Oct 16 16:43:59 2017    profiling_log.txt

         555404 function calls (543552 primitive calls) in 662.201 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 4510 to 20 due to restriction <20>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       23  661.233   28.749  661.233   28.749 {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
   115/80    0.177    0.002    0.211    0.003 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
      595    0.072    0.000    0.072    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
        1    0.045    0.045    0.045    0.045 {method 'acquire' of '_multiprocessing.SemLock' objects}
    897/1    0.044    0.000  662.202  662.202 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        3    0.042    0.014    0.042    0.014 {method 'read' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
2037/1974    0.037    0.000    0.082    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
      286    0.022    0.000    0.061    0.000 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/doccer.py:12(docformat)
     2886    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {built-in method posix.stat}
       79    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {built-in method posix.read}
      597    0.013    0.000    0.021    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:830(get_data)
      276    0.011    0.000    0.013    0.000 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py:250(_optimize_charset)
      108    0.011    0.000    0.038    0.000 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:626(_construct_argparser)
     1225    0.011    0.000    0.050    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1233(find_spec)
     7179    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {method 'splitlines' of 'str' objects}
       33    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {built-in method posix.waitpid}
      283    0.008    0.000    0.015    0.000 /Users/Reddy/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/doccer.py:128(indentcount_lines)
        3    0.008    0.003    0.008    0.003 {method 'poll' of 'select.poll' objects}
     7178    0.008    0.000    0.008    0.000 {method 'expandtabs' of 'str' objects}
      597    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.FileIO' objects}
```

More profiling info sorted by `percall` info:
[image: profiling info sorted by percall]

**Update 2**

The elements in the large list `datasets` I mentioned earlier are not usually as big - they are typically 10-25MB each. But depending on the floating point precision used, number of samples and features, this can easily grow to 500MB-1GB per element also. hence I'd prefer a solution that can scale.

**Update 3:**

The code inside holdout_trial_compare_datasets uses method GridSearchCV of scikit-learn, which internally uses joblib library if we set n_jobs > 1 (or whenever we even set it). This might lead to some bad interactions between multiprocessing and joblib. So trying another config where I do not set n_jobs at all (which should to default no parallelism within scikit-learn). Will keep you posted.

Comment: have you done any profiling?

Comment: not yet, as the parameters for which I would like to test it (16-32 processes, with 10-15 datasets) require me to run it on a cluster and I don't know how to profile python programs on the command line. I will look into it soon.

Comment: my 2¢: if your large data object only pass from parent to child, `Manager` seemed overkill, you could load it into a global variable in the parent, then it will be shared with child after `fork()`.

Comment: Thats another alternative, thanks.

Comment: it seems you’re profiling parent process, not the child worker?

Comment: It seems so.. not sure how to use cProfile to achieve profiling of child processes. Any tips?

Comment: You can use [a decorator to profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5375728/1513933) your `partial_func_holdout` function. Or use This: https://gist.github.com/nealtodd/2489618

Comment: aha, you started a bounty, have you tried to replace `Manager`? sharing data with Manager need pickle/unpickle, transport via PIPE, much much slower than in-memory share, and do not scale well.

Comment: Yeah, I really need a solution :).

Comment: I get conficting suggestions regarding Manager from the internet : some people say it really helps (I don't need to implement all the plumbing, and i don't want to ).. others, don't recommend :)

Comment: it is convenient, but not opti for speed.

Comment: I certainly don't want to implement the plumbing, as I am not sure if the speedup (if any) would be worth my weeks and weeks of time to learn and implement it properly. So looking for expert advice here :)

Comment: actually, that is much simpler than using a Manager.

Comment: Few things I would try are using `cv_results = pool.imap(partial_func_holdout, range(num_repetitions))` or `cv_results = pool.imap_unordered(partial_func_holdout, range(num_repetitions))`. Both of them will return a generator, which means you are not waiting for all the results and processing few results at a time. Also I would try and use `chunksize` parameters also and see if that helps.

Comment: @PradeepReddyRaamana have you tried using queue instead of proxy object?

Comment: @TarunLalwani good pointers - didn't think that would matter so far, will give them a try.

Comment: @Vinny, see my comment above.

Comment: @PradeepReddyRaamana I don't see you mention queues.. well, I've done some expiriments with Manager and Queues. Queues has their limitations, but they are a *lot faster.*

Comment: how do you get result back? save to disk or via shared variable?

Comment: I get them both ways - saved to disk, as well a list returned by Pool.map (which I’m not sure if it is shared ). The results are very small - not big concern.

Comment: @vinny, see 3rd comment above your original comment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on discussion in the comments, I did a mini experiment, compared three versions of implementation:

- v1: basically as same as your approach, in fact, as `partial(f1, *shared_inputs)` will unpack `proxy_manager.list` immediately, `Manager.List` not involved here, data passed to worker with the internal queue of `Pool`.
- v2: v2 made use `Manager.List`, work function will receive a `ListProxy` object, it fetches shared data via a internal connection to a server process.
- v3: child process share data from the parent, take advantage of `fork(2)` system call.

---

```
def f1(*args):
    for e in args[0]: pow(e, 2)

def f2(*args):
    for e in args[0][0]: pow(e, 2)

def f3(n):
    for i in datasets: pow(i, 2)

def v1(np):
    with mp.Manager() as proxy_manager:
        shared_inputs = proxy_manager.list([datasets,])
        pf = partial(f1, *shared_inputs)
        with mp.Pool(processes=np) as pool:
            r = pool.map(pf, range(16))

def v2(np):
    with mp.Manager() as proxy_manager:
        shared_inputs = proxy_manager.list([datasets,])
        pf = partial(f2, shared_inputs)
        with mp.Pool(processes=np) as pool:
            r = pool.map(pf, range(16))

def v3(np):
    with mp.Pool(processes=np) as pool:
        r = pool.map(f3, range(16))

datasets = [2.0 for _ in range(10 * 1000 * 1000)]
for f in (v1, v2, v3):
    print(f.__code__.co_name)
    for np in (2, 4, 8, 16):
        s = time()
        f(np)
        print("%s %.2fs" % (np, time()-s))
```

results taken on a 16 core E5-2682 VPC, it is obvious that v3 scales better: [image: result]

Comment: Thanks George - really helps me get closer to understanding the problem.

I am really curious about `*shared_inputs` unpacking immediately - I didn't realize that happens..similar thing would happen when we apply `functools.partial` also, as it tries the freeze the inputs and signature, right? So with or without unpacking, data must have been passed to the child processes via pickling, right? that means, the only we can avoid it is using them as global variables and accessing them from child processes? Any dangers with this method? No changes to input will be made within child processes.

Comment: as `*shared_inputs` unpacked list before `partial` take effect, it "freezes" objects that  (proxy) list contains, not the proxy itself, v2 it an example to use `Manager.List` with partial; yes data got pickle/unpickle to passing around; within the context of your problem and workload, there is nothing to worry about, if you passing something associated with external resources like socket object, file descriptor, you need to be more careful.

Comment: thanks George for your help - I feel like we need to better establish the bottlenecks .. esp with large objects (10 elements of 20MB) and complex calculations (something more demanding than squaring a regular grids of numbers, as that might trigger internal memoizations).. Your comments have been greatly helpful and I am hoping to nail this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects}
```

Looking at your profiler output I would say that the shared object lock/unlock overhead overwhelms the speed gains of multithreading.

Refactor so that the work is farmed out to workers that do not need to talk to one another as much.

Specifically, if possible, derive one answer per data pile and then act on the accumulated results.

This is why Queues can seem so much faster: they involve a type of work that does not require an object that has to be 'managed' and so locked/unlocked.

Only 'manage' things that absolutely need to be shared between processes. Your managed list contains some very complicated looking objects...

A faster paradigm is:

```
allwork = manager.list([a, b,c])
theresult = manager.list()
```

and then

```
while mywork:
    unitofwork = allwork.pop()
    theresult = myfunction(unitofwork)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and response. In fact, the work in different processes do NOT need to talk to each other all i.e. once they access the shared list of data `shared_inputs`, everything inside unit of work is independent of others.

Comment: And I am not sure how my implemented suggestion different from your suggestions. Could you try elaborating more, or perhaps write a more detailed implementation that can be swapped in place of what I show at the top? that'd be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need a complex shared object, then only use a list of the most simple objects imaginable.

Then tell the workers to acquire the complex data that they can process in their own little world.

Try:

```
allwork = manager.list([datasetid1, datasetid2 ,...])
theresult = manager.list()

while mywork:
    unitofworkid = allwork.pop()
    theresult = myfunction(unitofworkid)

def myfunction(unitofworkid):
    thework = acquiredataset(unitofworkid)
    result = holdout_trial_compare_datasets(thework, ...)
```

I hope that this makes sense. It should not take too much time to refactor in this direction. And you should see that {method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects} number drop like a rock when you profile.

Comment: Thanks, I need to think about it. This would lead to tremendous I/O in my situation - but need to think about if it’s only very small fraction of time compared to actual parallel computation..